# Issue in transffering ethers from account to contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp

This is the function I used to transfer the ethets:

`function addBalance(address beneficiary) payable returns(bool success){
        if (beneficiary.send(msg.value))
            throw;
        return true;
    }`

Call to the function using web3:

```
contract.addBalance.sendTransaction(contractAddress, 
        {from: senderAddress, to: contractAddress, gas:1000000, value: web3.toWei(7, "ether")},function (error, result){ 
            if(!error){

                } else{
                    console.log(error);
                }
        });
```

OR

```
contract.addBalance.sendTransaction(contractAddress, 
        {from: web3.eth.accounts[5], to: contractAddress, gas:1000000, value: web3.toWei(7, "ether")},function (error, result){ 
            if(!error){
                } else{
                    console.log(error);
                }
        });
```

When I call this It gives error Saying:

```
Error: authentication needed: password or unlock
at Object.InvalidResponse (errors.js:35)
at requestmanager.js:86
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (httpprovider.js:118)
```

I have already unlocked my account
If I change the sender address with address of coinbase it works fine, but not working with any other account address

The call which works fine is bellow :

```
contract.addBalance.sendTransaction(contractAddress, 
        {from: web3.eth.coinbase, to: contractAddress, gas:1000000, value: web3.toWei(7, "ether")},function (error, result){ 
            if(!error){

                } else{
                    console.log(error);
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unlock the account where you send the ethers from:

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
```

and insert the password in the `geth` console.

Comment: Thank you very much, It works, I haven't unlocked  that particular account and  try to transfer money from it, and hence it shows the error